# Error when trying to install Instant App

Tags: android, adb, android-instant-apps

I've a multi feature app.
Installed App version works perfectly.
n
Instant App version was working till yesterday. Now I can build it correctly but I get this error when trying to install any of the instant modules.

Does anyone have the same issue ?

I cannot understand the error message:

```
Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: Failed parse during installPackageLI: Failed to read manifest from /data/app/vmdl138992238.tmp/base.apk: For input string: "otb"
```

I do not have any otb string.
otb is a the name of a feature module, but not the one I'm tring to install

EDIT:
I tried to rename the module otb to ootb. I got the same error having it "For input string: "ootb""

also I retrieved the logcat stacktrace:

```
07-01 01:51:37.516 776-817/? W/PackageManager: Failed parse during installPackageLI
                                               android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to read manifest from /data/app/vmdl1025494079.tmp/base.apk
                                                   at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseBaseApk(PackageParser.java:1252)
                                                   at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseClusterPackage(PackageParser.java:1133)
                                                   at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackage(PackageParser.java:952)
                                                   at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackage(PackageParser.java:966)
                                                   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:16828)
                                                   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageTracedLI(PackageManagerService.java:16767)
                                                   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.-wrap29(Unknown Source:0)
                                                   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$7.run(PackageManagerService.java:14255)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
                                                   at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ootb"
                                                   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
                                                   at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:133)
                                                   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:373)
                                                   at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseActivity(PackageParser.java:4184)
                                                   at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseBaseApplication(PackageParser.java:3612)
                                                   at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseBaseApkCommon(PackageParser.java:2103)
                                                   at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseBaseApk(PackageParser.java:1984)
                                                   at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseBaseApk(PackageParser.java:1236)
                                                   at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseClusterPackage(PackageParser.java:1133) 
                                                   at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackage(PackageParser.java:952) 
                                                   at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackage(PackageParser.java:966) 
                                                   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:16828) 
                                                   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageTracedLI(PackageManagerService.java:16767) 
                                                   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.-wrap29(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$7.run(PackageManagerService.java:14255) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65) 
                                                   at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

Comment: Can you file a bug, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: I did not file a bug because I'm not sure that is really related to the compiling process or to my specific case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I maybe found the source of the problem for anyone having the same issue.
This may be related to android O SDK (API 26).

Compiling and targeting API 26 works correctly for classical app but is giving this error for instant apps at install time. 
Rolling back to compile SDK 25 solved the problem in my case.

I'll wait for the final API/gradle plugin before tryng again.